# SVG not working in Chrome

Tags: svg

This works in Firefox but not Chrome. Basically the animation works correctly in Firefox with the lightbulb glowing and the leaf growing but for some reason cannot get it to work in Chrome. Thanks for the help here.

jsfiddle here, http://jsfiddle.net/EfLtD/1/

```
        <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
             viewBox="0 0 250 250" enable-background="new 0 0 250 250" xml:space="preserve">
        <g id="light-bulb-6-icon_1_">
            <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M-314.3,152.1c-2.1,0-2.8-0.6-7.4-5c-0.6-0.6-1.4-1.3-2.2-2h25.6c-0.9,0.8-1.7,1.6-2.4,2.2
                c-4.6,4.3-5.3,4.8-7.4,4.8H-314.3z M-326.6,137.7c-1.7,0-3.1-1.4-3.1-3.1s1.4-3.1,3.1-3.1h31.2c1.7,0,3.1,1.4,3.1,3.1
                c0,1.7-1.4,3.1-3.1,3.1H-326.6z M-327.4,123.9c-1.7,0-3.1-1.4-3.1-3.1c0-1.7,1.4-3.1,3.1-3.1h32.7c0.9,0,1.7,0.4,2.3,1
                c0.5,0.6,0.8,1.3,0.8,2.1c0,1.8-1.4,3.1-3.1,3.1L-327.4,123.9L-327.4,123.9z M-298,109.7c0.3-13.3,6.4-23.6,12.4-33.5
                c6-10,11.6-19.4,11.6-31.5c0-16.9-11.6-35.1-37.1-35.1c-25.5,0-37,18.2-37,35.1c0,12.1,5.6,21.4,11.5,31.3
                c5.9,9.9,12,20.1,12.6,33.7h-9.1c-0.3-10.3-5.6-19.1-11.2-28.5c-6.4-10.8-13-21.9-13-36.5c0-13.7,5-25.2,14.4-33.2
                c8.4-7.2,19.7-11.1,31.9-11.1c12.1,0,23.4,3.9,31.8,11.1c9.4,8,14.4,19.5,14.4,33.2c0,14.6-6.6,25.7-13,36.5
                c-5.6,9.4-10.8,18.2-11.2,28.5L-298,109.7L-298,109.7z M-312.8,109.6c-3.3-14.5-1.4-40.1,6.7-54.6l2.4-4.3l-3.9,3.1
                c-5.2,4-9.9,14.2-11.6,21.9c-5.4-3.9-7.4-10.6-5.3-18.3c2.9-10.6,14-22,31.7-23.2c-2,1.8-3.6,4.2-4.5,7c-1.9,5.3-1.3,10.1-0.7,14.7
                c0.6,4.6,1.1,9-0.8,13.6c-2,4.8-6.1,7.9-11.3,8.4l-0.8,0.1l-0.1,0.8c-1,9.8,0.3,22.7,3.1,30.8L-312.8,109.6L-312.8,109.6z"/>
            <path fill="#225650" d="M-311,1.4c11.9,0,23,3.9,31.2,10.9c9.2,7.8,14.1,19.1,14.1,32.5c0,14.3-6.6,25.3-12.9,36
                c-5.5,9.2-10.6,17.9-11.3,28h-7c0.6-12.5,6.5-22.4,12.2-32c5.8-9.7,11.8-19.7,11.8-32c0-11.2-4.1-20.5-12-27.1
                c-6.9-5.8-16.2-9-26.1-9c-9.9,0-19.2,3.2-26.1,9c-7.8,6.6-12,16-12,27.1c0,12.4,5.7,21.8,11.6,31.9c5.7,9.5,11.5,19.3,12.4,32.1
                h-7.1c-0.6-10.1-5.8-18.8-11.3-28c-6.3-10.6-12.9-21.7-12.9-36c0-13.4,4.9-24.6,14.1-32.5C-334,5.2-322.9,1.4-311,1.4L-311,1.4
                 M-295.4,35.5c-1.2,1.6-2.2,3.4-2.9,5.4c-1.9,5.5-1.3,10.4-0.8,15.2c0.5,4.5,1.1,8.7-0.7,13.1c-1.8,4.5-5.6,7.3-10.4,7.8l-1.6,0.2
                l-0.2,1.6c-1,9.4,0.2,21.7,2.7,29.9h-2.7c-3-14.4-1.1-39.1,6.8-53.1l4.9-8.7l-7.8,6.1c-5.1,4-9.6,13.2-11.6,21
                c-4.1-3.7-5.5-9.6-3.7-16.2c1.6-5.9,5.5-11.4,11-15.4C-307.7,38.6-301.8,36.3-295.4,35.5 M-294.7,118.7c0.6,0,1.2,0.2,1.6,0.7
                c0.2,0.3,0.5,0.7,0.5,1.4l0,0v0c0,1.1-1,2.1-2.1,2.1h-32.7c-1.1,0-2.1-1-2.1-2.1c0-1.1,1-2.1,2.1-2.1L-294.7,118.7 M-295.4,132.5
                c1.2,0,2.1,0.9,2.1,2.1c0,1.1-1,2.1-2.1,2.1h-31.2c-1.1,0-2.1-1-2.1-2.1s1-2.1,2.1-2.1H-295.4 M-300.9,146.1
                c-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.3-0.5,0.5c-4.6,4.2-5.1,4.5-6.7,4.5h-6.2c-1.6,0-2.1-0.4-6.7-4.7c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.3H-300.9 M-311-0.6
                c-23.6,0-47.3,15.1-47.3,45.3c0,28.1,24.2,43.8,24.2,66h11.1c-0.6-28-24.1-41.7-24.1-66c0-22.8,18-34.1,36-34.1S-275,22-275,44.7
                c0,24.3-24,38.7-24,66h11c0-22.2,24.2-37.9,24.2-66C-263.8,14.5-287.4-0.6-311-0.6L-311-0.6z M-289.6,33.1
                c-33.2,0-46.5,33.8-28.9,44.2c1.5-8.4,6.5-18.9,11.5-22.8c-8.3,14.8-10.3,41.2-6.6,56.1h7.1c-3.1-8-4.5-21.8-3.5-31.7
                c5-0.5,9.8-3.4,12.1-9c3.9-9.7-2.1-18.1,1.5-28.4C-295.1,37.7-292.7,34.9-289.6,33.1L-289.6,33.1z M-294.7,116.7h-32.7
                c-2.3,0-4.1,1.9-4.1,4.1c0,2.3,1.9,4.1,4.1,4.1h32.7c2.3,0,4.1-1.9,4.1-4.1C-290.5,118.5-292.4,116.7-294.7,116.7L-294.7,116.7z
                 M-295.4,130.5h-31.2c-2.3,0-4.1,1.9-4.1,4.1c0,2.3,1.9,4.1,4.1,4.1h31.2c2.3,0,4.1-1.9,4.1-4.1
                C-291.3,132.3-293.1,130.5-295.4,130.5L-295.4,130.5z M-295.7,144.1h-30.7c8.1,7.5,8.9,9,12.1,9h6.2
                C-304.9,153.1-304.2,151.7-295.7,144.1L-295.7,144.1z"/>
        </g>
        <g>
            <path fill="#F9E46E" class="yellow" d="M89.5,93.2c0,24.3,23.5,38,24.1,66h24c0-27.3,24-41.7,24-66C161.6,47.7,89.5,47.7,89.5,93.2z"/>
        </g>
        <g id="light-bulb-6-icon_37_">
            <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M122.2,200.9c-2.1,0-2.8-0.6-7.4-5c-0.6-0.6-1.4-1.3-2.2-2h25.6c-0.9,0.8-1.7,1.6-2.4,2.2
                c-4.6,4.3-5.3,4.8-7.4,4.8H122.2z M109.9,186.5c-1.7,0-3.1-1.4-3.1-3.1s1.4-3.1,3.1-3.1h31.2c1.7,0,3.1,1.4,3.1,3.1
                c0,1.7-1.4,3.1-3.1,3.1H109.9z M109.1,172.7c-1.7,0-3.1-1.4-3.1-3.1c0-1.7,1.4-3.1,3.1-3.1h32.7c0.9,0,1.7,0.4,2.3,1
                c0.5,0.6,0.8,1.3,0.8,2.1c0,1.8-1.4,3.1-3.1,3.1L109.1,172.7L109.1,172.7z M138.6,158.5c0.3-13.3,6.4-23.6,12.4-33.5
                c6-10,11.6-19.4,11.6-31.5c0-16.9-11.6-35.1-37.1-35.1S88.4,76.6,88.4,93.5c0,12.1,5.6,21.4,11.5,31.3c5.9,9.9,12,20.1,12.6,33.7
                h-9.1c-0.3-10.3-5.6-19.1-11.2-28.5c-6.4-10.8-13-21.9-13-36.5c0-13.7,5-25.2,14.4-33.2c8.4-7.2,19.7-11.1,31.9-11.1
                c12.1,0,23.4,3.9,31.8,11.1c9.4,8,14.4,19.5,14.4,33.2c0,14.6-6.6,25.7-13,36.5c-5.6,9.4-10.8,18.2-11.2,28.5L138.6,158.5
                L138.6,158.5z"/>
            <path fill="#225650" d="M122.3,201.9h6.2c3.2,0,3.9-1.4,12.4-9h-30.7C118.3,200.4,119,201.9,122.3,201.9z M135.2,195.3
                c-4.6,4.2-5.1,4.5-6.7,4.5h-6.2c-1.6,0-2.1-0.4-6.7-4.7c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.3h20.5C135.5,195,135.3,195.2,135.2,195.3z"/>
            <path fill="#225650"d="M141.1,179.3h-31.2c-2.3,0-4.1,1.9-4.1,4.1c0,2.3,1.9,4.1,4.1,4.1h31.2c2.3,0,4.1-1.9,4.1-4.1
                C145.2,181.1,143.4,179.3,141.1,179.3z M141.1,185.5h-31.2c-1.1,0-2.1-1-2.1-2.1s1-2.1,2.1-2.1h31.2c1.2,0,2.1,0.9,2.1,2.1
                C143.2,184.5,142.3,185.5,141.1,185.5z"/>
            <path fill="#225650" d="M125.5,48.1c-23.6,0-47.3,15.1-47.3,45.3c0,28.1,24.2,43.8,24.2,66h11.1c-0.6-28-24.1-41.7-24.1-66
                c0-22.8,18-34.1,36.1-34.1s36,11.4,36,34.1c0,24.3-24,38.7-24,66h11c0-22.2,24.2-37.9,24.2-66C172.8,63.2,149.1,48.1,125.5,48.1z
                 M146.6,157.5h-7c0.6-12.5,6.5-22.4,12.2-32c5.8-9.7,11.8-19.7,11.8-32c0-11.2-4.1-20.5-12-27.1c-6.9-5.8-16.2-9-26.1-9
                s-19.2,3.2-26.1,9c-7.8,6.6-12,16-12,27.1c0,12.4,5.7,21.8,11.6,31.9c5.7,9.5,11.5,19.3,12.4,32.1h-7.1c-0.6-10.1-5.8-18.8-11.3-28
                c-6.3-10.6-12.9-21.7-12.9-36c0-13.4,4.9-24.6,14.1-32.5c8.2-7,19.3-10.9,31.2-10.9c11.9,0,23,3.9,31.2,10.9
                c9.2,7.8,14.1,19.1,14.1,32.5c0,14.3-6.6,25.3-12.9,36C152.4,138.6,147.2,147.3,146.6,157.5z"/>
            <path fill="#225650" d="M141.8,165.5h-32.7c-2.3,0-4.1,1.9-4.1,4.1c0,2.3,1.9,4.1,4.1,4.1h32.7c2.3,0,4.1-1.9,4.1-4.1
                C146,167.3,144.1,165.5,141.8,165.5z M143.9,169.5L143.9,169.5c0,1.2-1,2.1-2.1,2.1h-32.7c-1.1,0-2.1-1-2.1-2.1
                c0-1.1,1-2.1,2.1-2.1h32.7v0c0.6,0,1.2,0.2,1.6,0.7C143.7,168.4,144,168.8,143.9,169.5L143.9,169.5z"/>
        </g>
        <path fill="#FFFFFF" class="leaf" stroke="#225650" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M121.8,158.6c-3.3-14.5-1.4-40.1,6.7-54.6
            l2.4-4.3l-3.9,3.1c-5.2,4-9.9,14.2-11.6,21.9c-5.4-3.9-7.4-10.6-5.3-18.3c2.9-10.6,14-22,31.7-23.2c-2,1.8-3.6,4.2-4.5,7
            c-1.9,5.3-1.3,10.1-0.7,14.7c0.6,4.6,1.1,9-0.8,13.6c-2,4.8-6.1,7.9-11.3,8.4l-0.8,0.1l-0.1,0.8c-1,9.8,0.3,22.7,3.1,30.8
            L121.8,158.6L121.8,158.6z"/>
        </svg>
```

/* CSS */

```
/* Globe */
#yellow-globe {width: 300px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;}


@keyframes yellow {
          0% {
              fill: #FFFFFF;
          }
          25% {
              fill: #FFFFFF;
          }
          50% {
              fill: #F9E46E;
          }
          75% {
              fill: #F9E46E;
          }
          100% {
              fill: #F9E46E;
          }
      }

      .yellow {
          fill: yellow;
          animation-name: yellow;
          animation-duration: 1s;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      }

 .leaf {
   stroke-dasharray: 242;
   stroke-dashoffset: 242;
   animation: dash 4s linear alternate;
   animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@keyframes dash {
      from {
        stroke-dashoffset: 242;
      }
      to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      }
}
@keyframes fillme {
          0% {
              fill: #FFFFFF;
          }
          25% {
              fill: #FFFFFF;
          }
          50% {
              fill: #225650;
          }
          75% {
              fill: #225650;
          }
          100% {
              fill: #225650;
          }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the `-webkit-` prefix on animations (and transitions) for webkit browsers (like Chrome). [Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/EfLtD/2/)

You may also want to include the `-ms-` and `-moz-` prefixes so that you can reach older versions of FireFox and IE as well

Comment: this works well, thank you. I tried adding the -ms prefix for IE but does not seem to work. I thought that IE10+ supported the standard @ keyframes syntax or am I missing anything. Thanks for the help!